# How to accurately fetch Unix permissions a user has on a given fs object?

Tags: permissions, filesystems

This is the logic I have now:

```
  int getInodePermissions(final int uid, final int[] gids, final fsObject inode)
  {
     final int inodeOwner = getOwner(inode);
     final int inodeGroup = getGroup(inode);
     final int inodeMode = getMode(inode);

     int perm;
     if (uid == inodeOwner) {
         perm = (inodeMode >> 6) & 7;
     } else if (isUserInGroup(inodeGroup, gids)) {
        perm = (inodeMode >> 3) & 7;
     } else {
        perm = inodeMode & 7;
     }
     return perm;
  }
```

But I just realized that if we have e.g. `x` bit as owner and `w` bit as group, we should you get both `x` and `w`.  I tried looking up some tutorials but they explain individual access not combinations of different groups. Could some either direct me to such a description or list all cases so I can make sure I'm not missing any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if we have e.g. x bit as owner and w bit as group, we should you get both x and w

Nope!  If you are the owner, you get the owner permissions, *not* the group permissions, even if you are also in the group.  For example:

```
> touch example.file
```

Presuming `example.file` did not already exist, if you have a normal umask, the file's permissions will be 664, with your eponymous group as the group.  Now:

```
> sudo chmod 077 example.file
> echo whatever >> example.file
bash: example.file: Permission denied
```

Even though you are in the group and the group has rwx permission, you are denied because you are the owner, and the owner has no permissions.

So, what you already have is correct!

Comment: I understand using | but I want to know if that matches the permissions we are expected to use.

Comment: Do we need to use permissions from `others` too?

Comment: Hmmm...whoops. Like you, I was assuming that if the user is both the owner and a member of the group, that user  gets both sets of permissions.  But this turns out to be wrong -- I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks :) Btw, another quick question if you don't mind. If I have to define READ, WRITE AND EXECUTE constants would defining them as 4 instead of 0x4, or 2 instead of 0x2 and 1 instead of 0x1 make any difference?

Comment: It won't make any difference since 0x4 (hexadecimal) == 4 (decimal), and that stays true right up to 0x9.  After that you have to convert them, 0xa == 10, 0x10 == 16, etc.  Remember to tick this as an answer if you're happy.